# NEST: Update source filter

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a method that takes a query as parameter like:

```cs
public ISearchResponse<Object> SearchComponent(SearchDescriptor<Object> query)
{
  ...
}
```

In this query I want to add a source filter like:

```cs
public ISearchResponse<Object> SearchComponent(SearchDescriptor<Object> query)
{
    query = query.Source(sf =>
                    sf.Exclude(e => e
                        .Field("SomeField")
                        ));
    ...
}
```

But what happens if the query already have a source filter? This filter will override that filter right? How can I update the existing queries source filter?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work but it's not the most beautiful solution. Anyone that can come up with a better alternative?

```
public ISearchResponse<Object> SearchComponent(ISearchRequest query)
{
    var excludeFields = new List<string>();
    excludeFields.Add("SomeField");

    if (query.Source == null)
    {
        query.Source = new SourceFilter {Include = "*", Exclude = excludeFields.ToArray()};
    }
    else if (query.Source.Exclude == null)
    {
        query.Source.Exclude = excludeFields.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        query.Source.Exclude.And(excludeFields.ToArray());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is obviously bad because of that cast. If your method needs to treat `query` as `ISearchRequest` you might as well use that as the method's parameter. Also, no need to check if `excludeFields` has anything since you add something to it just before that.
Other than that, your solution seems a readable approach - you could squeeze it to a one-liner but that would be less readable (and undesirable as such)

Comment: The cast and if case are there because this is a simplification of my real life case. I will update the sample accordingly.

Comment: If all you do is add a single field (and this is not again some kind of simplification), then creating a list is an overkill. `query.Source.Exclude = new [] { "SomeField" }` would do. Remember - lists initialize with a default capacity of 16, while using a simple array will take only the necessary space for the operation.

Comment: The list can in real life be much longer... The problem I see is that if there already is a filter set to the query by someone else then I need to update the query instead of setting a new filter.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of Nest than what I have and this has changed a bit, but I figure you can do something along these lines:

```
var exclude = query.Source?.Exclude; 
query.Source = new SourceFilter() { Excludes =  (exclude ?? new Field[0]).Union(moreFields) };
```

Comment: I tried to upgrade my solution to 5.x but I don't understand how Union works? :) Could you give an example of how you would do it in 5.x?

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed your comment. Do you still need that example?

Comment: Yes please! :) Thank you!